# How to convert following Karnaugh map to a simplified Boolean expression?

Tags: karnaugh-map

This is the Karnaugh map which I draw for F = A'B'C'+AB'C+A'BC+ABC'
But  I am not sure how to simplify the Boolean expression for this as there are no groups here
[image]

Comment: I don't think you can simplify that further by the traditional (and, or, not) methods, but those 'checkerboard' patterns can often be fit onto xor. In this case I'm guessing you could simplify the whole thing as (A xor B xor C)'.

Comment: Actually, it looks like B has no effect at all.  I think it's (A xor C)'.

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be further simplified with a Karnaugh map, but with a little Boolean algebra:

\$F = \bar A \bar B \bar C + A \bar B C + \bar A B C + A B \bar C\$
\$F = \bar A( \bar B \bar C + B C) + A (\bar B C + B \bar C)\$
\$F = \bar A . \overline {(B \oplus C)} + A . (B \oplus C)\$

let \$(B \oplus C) = X\$

\$F = \bar A \bar X + A X\$
\$F = \overline {(A \oplus X)}\$

now substituting X:

\$F = \overline { (A \oplus B \oplus C) }\$

Answer (score 0):

The XOR's and XNOR's do not correspond to a binary theorem.  You have to learn to recognize the pattern.

In this case it is an XNOR.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline A & B & F \\\hline
  0 & 0 & 1\\\hline
  0 & 1 & 0 \\\hline
  1 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
  1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
\end{array}$$

$$ F = \overline {A \oplus B}$$

[image: XNOR]

Answer (score 0):

If you already know how an XOR gate behaves you could simplify this intuitively.

Basically XOR does the following

A B O/P 
0 0 0
0 1   1
1 0   1
1 1   0

So as the number of inputs increases the output can be generalized to be 1 when there are odd ones in the input and 0 when there are even.

so if you look the K-map you have alternating one's and zero's which means that every box on going vertically  or horizontally changes from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1. And on moving one step horizontally or vertically reflects a change in the number of one's by one.

So you can easily come to the understanding that in such a configuration the output is linked to the number of ones in the input.

All you need to do is figure out if the relation is odd to 1 or even to 1 and you are set.